# How to test if a bag is empty in Pig Latin?

Tags: apache-pig, latin

I have a bag say C, that may may come back empty from an operation.
I want to test whether or not C is empty,
And if so populate a new tuple in a different bag with value 'true'; otherwise 'false'.
The difficulty I think is, it's testing the C bag as a whole, and if so populate a new tuple in a different bag, not C.
I tried:
grunt> E = FILTER C BY not IsEmpty(C);
And get

2014-05-01 14:12:28,065 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
 Invalid scalar projection: C_grouped : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Seems like Pig expects me to first do a join on C first? I.e. I am not using this right ..

Thanks!

Comment: Do `DESCRIBE C` and see what you get.

Comment: ok i solved my problem. The error Pig gives is very confusing and not related. What i needed to do was a GROUP BY  first on my bag, and then IsEmpty works ..

Comment: FLATTEN also can be used to remove empty bags

Answer (score 0):

As the answer was already posted in the comments:

> What i needed to do was a GROUP BY first on my bag, and then IsEmpty
>   works